# How does one change the default .git/config contents when creating/cloning a git repo?

Tags: git

Every time you create or clone a git repo, git creates a local .git/config file that you can use to set local project-level git configs that won't be checked in to source. On my version of git (2.17.1), it looks like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
```

Is it possible to change this default .git/config template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change it through the `git clone [--template=<template_directory>]` option.

That option is detailed in [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory)

> Files and directories in the template directory whose name do not start with a dot will be copied to the `$GIT_DIR` after it is created.

That can include a default `config` file.